# Search for a pattern in Column in a CSV and replace another pattern in the same line using sed command

Tags: linux, shell, sed, command

I want to check for a pattern (only if the pattern starts with) in second column in a CSV file and if that pattern exists then replace something else in same line.

I wrote the following sed command for following csv to change the I to N if the pattern 676 exists in second column. But it checks 676 in the 7th and 9th  column also since the ,676 exists. Ideally, I want only the second line to be checked for if the prefix 676 exists. All I want is to check 676 prefixed in second column (pattern not in the middle or end of the second value Ex- 46769777) and then do the change on ,I, to ,N,.

```
sed -i  '/,676/ {; s/,I,/,N,/;}' temp.csc

6768880,55999777,S,I,TTTT,I,67677,yy
6768880,676999777,S,I,TTTT,I,67677,yy 
6768880,46769777,S,I,TTTT,I,67677,yy
```

Expected result required

```
6768880,55999777,S,I,TTTT,I,67677,yy
6768880,676999777,S,N,TTTT,N,67677,yy
6768880,40999777,S,I,TTTT,I,67677,yy
```

Comment: difficult to write supportable code in `sed` that can do this. Do  you really care if it is `sed`? `awk` is designed with these sort of problems in mind and will be very easy to implement. Good luck.

Comment: You have an error in your output.  How does `46769777` become `40999777`

Answer (score 2):

This requires that `676` appear at the beginning of the second column before any changes are made:

```
$ sed   '/^[^,]*,676/ s/,I,/,N,/g' file
6768880,55999777,S,I,TTTT,I,67677,yy
6768880,676999777,S,N,TTTT,N,67677,yy 
6768880,46769777,S,I,TTTT,I,67677,yy
```

Notes:

- The regex `/^[^,]*,676/` requires that `676` appear after the first appearance of a comma on the line.  In more detail:

  - `^` matches the beginning of the line
  - `[^,]*` matches the first column
  - `,676` matches the first comma followed by `676`
- In your desired output, `,I,` was replaced with `,N,` every time it appeared on the line.  To accomplish this, `g` (meaning global) was added to the substitute command.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not bound by `sed`, `awk` might be a better option for you. Give this a try :

```
awk -F"," '{match($2,/^676/)&&gsub(",I",",N")}{print}' temp.csc
```

`match` syntax does the matching of second column to numbers that starts with (`^`) 676. `gsub` replaces `I` with `N`.

Result:

 `6768880,55999777,S,I,TTTT,I,67677,yy
 6768880,676999777,S,N,TTTT,N,67677,yy 
 6768880,46769777,S,I,TTTT,I,67677,yy`

Comment: Could be shorten some to: `awk -F, '{match($2,/^676/)&&gsub(",I",",N")}1'`

Comment: Can be further shortened: `awk -F, '$2~/^676/{gsub(",I",",N")}1'`